# My meta boxes update wp_postmeta of posts but not of pages. What is wrong with the code?

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I have a simple checkbox on posts to display posts in a slider, and everything works fine. But I want to switch and add only pages in the slider, but code below is not updating wp_postmeta table of the pages, only posts. Could you please direct me what am I doing wrong

```
function damad_add_post_metabox() {

$screens = array( 'post', 'page');

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'damad_post_meta_id',
        __( 'Options', 'damad' ),
        'damad_inner_custom_box',
        $screen
    );
}
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'damad_add_post_metabox' );

function damad_inner_custom_box( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'damad_inner_custom_box', 'damad_inner_custom_box_nonce' );

  $homepage = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_featured', true);
  echo '<label for="post-featured">';
       _e("Include in homepage slider", 'damad');
  echo "</label>";
  echo '<input type="checkbox" id="post-featured" name="post-featured" value="post-featured"';
  if ( 'post-featured' == $homepage ) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
  } 
  echo '/>';
}

 function damad_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  if ( ! isset( $_POST['damad_inner_custom_box_nonce'] ) )
   return $post_id;

  $nonce = $_POST['damad_inner_custom_box_nonce'];

  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'damad_inner_custom_box' ) )
     return $post_id;

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return $post_id;

  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

  if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

 } else {

   if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;
 }

$featureddata = $_POST['post-featured'];

  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_featured', $featureddata );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'damad_save_postdata' );
```

Comment: Try and debug it, remove all the conditions from the `damad_save_postdata()` except `if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return $post_id;` and see if this works and if it does then put the conditions one by one and get hold of the culprit :)

Comment: @MarutiMohanty thanks, in the mean time I realised that any sort of meta data on pages is not saved, tried adding fields with advanced custom field plugin, and it is not saved either, so problem lays somewhere else... which is a bad news :(

Comment: ok change back to any default theme in case you are not and check the same ... if it works then its the theme you need to look into

Comment: @MarutiMohanty actually what I realised is that only meta fields are being updated on only one page, others are not picking it up, no matter if i use plugin or code above... any thoughts what could cause that?

Comment: Check for something such in your active theme's `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
```

To

```
if ( 'page' == get_post_type($post_id) ) {
```

Comment: that didn't do it, that if statement is there to check if the user has permission to perform the save.